# How to change my Angularjs $scope to accept a JavaScript variable type string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following angularjs scope that:

```
$scope.Zips = {};
```

Is there a way for my angularjs scope to accept a variable that is a string? I would like to retrieve my string (that is a list) in the following function:

```
$scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
    try{
        $scope.Zips = $parse(getZipCodes());
    } catch(err) {

    }
}
```

The following is the function in JavaScript that retrieves the list of Zip Codes:

```
function getZipCodes() {
        var miles = document.getElementById("miles").options[document.getElementById("miles").selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        var zips_within_radius = document.getElementById("zipsWithinRadius");
        // debugger;
        if (typeof zip === 'undefined' || typeof miles === 'undefined' || !zip.length || !miles.length) return false;

    var zips = getZips();
        var zip_list = "";
    if (zips.length) {
            zip_list = zips.join();
            zips_within_radius.value = zip_list;
    }
        return zip_list;
  }
```

Image on what I am seeing:

[image]

The issue I am having is in my form, I have the following:

```
<input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5"
       ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
```

I would like the `ng-model="searchParam.Zip"` to retrieve the list I am getting from the list instead from the user input.

Comment: You can put whatever you want on the scope

Comment: @FrankModica: I understand that but I am not able to see the values that are being passed in.

Comment: You mean see them in the HTML? If so, you should show the template.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(getZipCodes())` or `console.log ($parse(getZipCodes()))`?

Comment: @FrankModica: I am not getting anything. I would like to see if the list is being passed through. Currently, I only see the zip code that was entered

Comment: So really you just want to debug your method that is getting zip codes? You can type `debugger` in it to set a breakpoint, and open the dev tools and walk through the code.

Comment: @FrankModica: I have tried that and I dont see the list. That is the issue I am encountering

Comment: Then you need to figure out which part of the `getZipCodes` method isn't working. When you walk through the code after setting a breakpoint, at what point do things start to go wrong?

Comment: @FrankModica: What goes wrong is when it passes in the Zip Code list. It only passes the first value (which is the first entry I entered) and not the list that I got . Posted what I am seeing

Comment: To input a list, use the `ng-list` directive. For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-list` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList).

Answer (score 0):

I think what @FrankModica is saying is, if you need to store an array of zips (strings) in your scope, you can do that rather than thinking of it as a JSON object:

```
$scope.Zips = [];
```

Have `getZipCodes()` return an array and you get what it seems you're looking for.

If you want to keep `getZipCodes()` the way you have it, then just declare the var without a type or as an empty string:

```
$scope.Zips;
$scope.Zips = '';
```

You may want to reconsider passing the value into the `$scope` as a single string, but if that really works for your use case there you go.

Comment: @ jgraff: So there isn't a way for the scope to accept a string that is a list?

Comment: Would i need to update the following code: if(searchParam){
     //debugger;
     $scope.formModel = searchParam;
     for(var param in searchParam){
      if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
       var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
       if (paramValue.length)
        queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
      }
     }
    }

Comment: Better yet. I need the following $scope.ZipsWithinRadius to be included in the searchParam query string. How can I do that? That is the problem I am seeing. It isnt passing the value over

Comment: I think it's time to back up and decide what pattern you want to follow. Passing big string values by query string is risky and hard to manage. Typically you would call a service to retrieve data for your model. I would encourage you to look up some examples of getting data from services before going further down this route.